# the action can´t be completed because the folder is open in R session

Tags: r, windows-10, ncdf4

I'm using package ncdf4 to read .nc file. After extracting the data, the .nc file stays open by RStudio, so I can't delete or rename the file in windows (I receive the error: "the action can´t be completed because the folder is open in RStudio R session"). There are no connections open. `unlink` doesn't solve the problem. The only thing that solves the issue is restarting R session. Any ideas for solution without restarting R?

```
library(ncdf4)
nc_data <- nc_open("DYsim.nc")
Tcalc <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "dyresmTEMPTURE_Var")
remove(nc_data)
```

Comment: Take a look at `nc_close`.

Comment: Thanks @tester, but `nc_close` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Updating ncdf4 to version 1.19 and using `nc_close` solved the issue.